# What does it mean when the $1s$ and $2s$ orbitals overlap?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

The shape of the $s$ orbital is spherical. Consequently the $1s$ orbital will be a sphere with nucleus as its center while $2s$ will be a similar but bigger sphere.

Now orbitals represent the space in which the electron could be found. But we see that the spaces of $1s$ and $2s$  overlap. So does that mean that a $1s$ and $2s$  electron could be potentially found at the same energy level i.e. at the same distance from the nucleus? There is also a possibility that the 1s electron could lie further from the nucleus than the $2s$ electron. How do we know, in this case, that the $1s$ and $2s$  electron have different energies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the theoretical explanation that you are being given in chemistry is incomplete. I wouldn't call it false because it is a very useful approximation that explains pretty much everything that we need in entry level chemistry "well enough" (even quantitatively), but it's just not how quantum mechanics of many-particle systems actually works. Let's try to clarify what is really happening.

The orbitals that you are used to from the drawings in physics and chemistry books are the single electron wave functions of hydrogen. In classical physics these orbitals would indeed "overlap" for a multi-electron wave function. Quantum mechanics doesn't work that way, though. A multi-particle wave function doesn't live in the same Hilbert space as a single particle wave function. Instead it lives in the product of several such Hilbert spaces, i.e. it is a higher dimensional distribution than the single electron function. For a single electron atom like hydrogen we can write the wave function as ψ(r). For a two electron atom, however, it becomes ψ(r1,r2), i.e. it now depends on six coordinates rather than three. For n-electrons we have to use ψ(r1,r2,⋯,ri), so we need a 3n-dimensional function to represent the system correctly.

That we can draw orbitals for the hydrogen problem is a mere coincidence because the spatial dimensionality of the solution happens to have the same three dimensions as space itself. For two electrons, however, the actual solution of the corresponding Schroedinger equation would live in six dimensions and so on. This can not be visualized easily. In the "orbital approximation" we are replacing this higher dimensional solution with a much more simple product:

ψ(r1,r2,⋯,ri)≈φ1(r1)φ2(r2)⋯φi(ri)

and we further assume that the electrons (described by the φi(ri) functions) behave independently like in a single electron atom. The reason why we are doing this is because the Schroedinger equation for the full 3n dimensional many-body problem can't be solved in closed form. Even the approximation problem is hard, but it can be analyzed sufficiently well to extract important information about atoms other than hydrogen and even molecules.

Comment: Your answer somewhat cleared things up but also stirred other doubts. As I understand, these spaces aren't physical and are to be taken in a more abstract sense. If that is so, what do the spatial representations of the orbitals, their different configurations, etc. represent? Are they all only true for the hydrogen atom?

Comment: One can make "realistic" plots for electric charge density, for instance, but how important is that to a chemist? I would argue that it's mostly irrelevant. In chemistry we care about binding energy, which these plots can not predict. Chemistry also involves only the outermost regions of atoms and molecules. What happens in inner orbitals is next to irrelevant because those electrons have ionization energies in the tens, hundreds and thousands of eV, far beyond the chemical energy scale. That's the reason why the simplified "hydrogen-like" orbital models work.

Comment: With regards to the question if simple orbitals are "only" valid for hydrogen... yes. The Schroedinger equation, even if we include spin, is only reasonably exact for hydrogen. Since electrons have a rather small rest mass, atoms with Z>1 require relativistic calculations to predict spectra correctly. Multi-electron atoms are notoriously difficult to calculate from first principles. However, if we want to calculate chemical binding energies with a precision of 10% or so, then we can approximate with hydrogen-like wave-functions reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

The $1S$ and $2S$ electrons can't be found in the same energy state, because the $1s$ and $2S$ electrons are in different energy states. Moreover, in the straight Coulomb approximation to the hydrogen atom: those states are stationary states, they never change, other than an unobservable global phase rotation.

Of course, in real life, there are various interaction terms (and other terms) that make them only approximate states, hence : transitions are allowed.

Your logic goes off the rails when you state, *"orbitals represent the space in which the electron could be found"*. This is a common misconception from various explanations of an electron randomly moving around, weighted by the wave function. This is just a far too classical attempt to explain the atom.

The wave function is a complex probability amplitude (not a probability distribution), which has no classical analog, so that it is best understood mathematically.

The idea that it represents the probability distribution of where and electron can be found will only lead to confusion: all the hydrogen wave functions are non-zero, everywhere, except at nodes, which have measure zero.

Moreover, you can't localize the electron, experimentally. How would you do it? If you do it theoretically by applying the $\bf{\hat{x}}$ operator and putting in an eigenstate, the $\psi({\bf x}) \propto \delta{\bf x})$, and it is no longer in an energy eigenstate; rather, it is a sum over all states that yields a delta function. (That is a standard property of spherical harmonics, and then you need to include the radial wave functions too).